# Load FBX file in Android Daydream app with Google VR SDK

Tags: android, google-vr, daydream, google-vr-sdk

I'm trying to build an application that will display a video content with a VR experience like a home theater.

I know how to play the video itself using the [google vr sdk samples](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk)

But is it possible to load a FBX file, like in Unity scene?

Comment: http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2011/08/23/announcing-rajawali-an-opengl-es-2-0-based-3d-framework-for-android/

Comment: http://www.goprogramming.space/unity-and-android-studio-integration/

Comment: @FebiMathew Thanks for answering, I know how to embedded unity into android project. But I looking for a way to use only Google VR SDK / Daydream and load a background using FBX file.
(BTW this is a post of mine about embedded unity into android: https://medium.com/@davidbeloosesky/embedded-unity-within-android-app-7061f4f473a#.p2d3bh79u)